# Creating Matrix in Python from numbers separated by spaces

Tags: python, matrix

I have an undefined matrix of numbers in a .txt separated only by spaces. How can I use python to define the matrix and manipulate it while keeping the order of rows and columns? Example of .txt document:

```
0.6225E+0    0.2679E+03   0.0000E+00    
0.0000E+00  -0.0000E+00   0.0000E+00
```

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('c:/~/trainSetRel3.txt', sep='\t')` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

mymatrix = np.loadtxt('input_file.txt')

>>> mymatrix

array([[   0.6225,  267.9   ,    0.    ],
       [   0.    ,   -0.    ,    0.    ]])
```

Do whatever you like with this matrix (2D array) then!